# Error shows EventDescriptionData cannot be converted to List<EventDescriptionData>

Tags: java, android

I am facing to solve this problem for few days I declared array in json. In this code where error show like incompatible types: EventDescriptionData cannot be converted to List i.e setAdapter I am not able to pass proper parameter . Please anyone help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_layout);
    }

    @Parcel
    public static class EventDescriptionData {
        /* Data for Pre Event Ticket Crausal Card  */
        @SerializedName("children")
        public List<carouselImage> mPreEventCrausal;      
        }

        @Parcel
        public static class carouselImage {
            @SerializedName("src")
            public String mImgSrc;
        }
}

public class CardPreEventDhamakaView extends LinearLayout {

    private CardPreEventDhamakaView(final Context context, MainActivity .EventDescriptionData eventData) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_preevent_dhamaka, this, true);

        CardView view = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardPreEventParentView);
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.cardPreEventgallery);
        gallery.setAdapter(new CardPreEventDhamakaViewData(getContext(), eventData));
    }

    public static class CardPreEventDhamakaViewData extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private List<MainActivity.EventDescriptionData> mCardData;
        public CardPreEventDhamakaViewData(Context context , List<MainActivity.EventDescriptionData> eventData)
        {
            mContext=context;
            mCardData = eventData;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mCardData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        public long getItemId(int i) { return i; }

        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(mCardData.get(i).mPreEventCrausal.get(i).mImgSrc)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_carousel).into(imageView);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a Listview  you have to pass a collection ie) group of objects. Here EventDescriptionData  is a single object. Either you create a collection of EventDescriptionData  objects and pass it to adapter. You cannot convert a EventDescriptionData  object to other type EventDescriptionData 
Here PreEventDetailsActivity.EventDescriptionData -> There is no where PreEventDetailsActivity in your code.

Comment: @Shriram MainActivity is a PreEventDetailsActivity

Answer (score 0):

EventDescriptionData public List mPreEventCrausal is a collection of carouseImage. Either pass this list as a parameter to your base adapter or else create a collection of PreEventDetailsActivity.EventDescriptionData and pass the list.

```
public CardPreEventDhamakaViewData(Context context , List<PreEventDetailsActivity.EventDescriptionData> eventData) --> no where you are creating a list of EventDescriptionData objects.
```